# Como verificar se após selecionado um arquivo o mesmo ainda existe no diretório em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, aplicação-web

Na minha aplicação utilizo como framework de javascript o angularJS, e para fazer a seleção dos arquivos utilizo o seguinte button:

```
 <md-button class="md-accent md-raised button-arquivo-margin"
                   ng-disabled="vm.controladorRequisicao.requisicaoSolicitada"
                   aria-label="Arquivo(s)">
            <div layout="row"
                 layout-align="center start"
                 flex>
                <input class="input-selecao"
                       im-file-change="vm.metodos.selecionarArquivos($event, arquivos)"
                       type="file"
                       multiple />
                <i class="icon-file s30"></i>
                <span class="title">Arquivo(s)</span>
            </div>
 </md-button>
```

onde `im-file-change="vm.metodos.selecionarArquivos($event, arquivos)"` é somente uma diretiva que obtém os arquivos do event do input e realiza o bind com meu model.
Após seleciona os arquivos os mesmo são exibidos em uma tabela conforme demonstrado abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém estou tendo um problema de má usabilidade do sistema, no qual as pessoas estão movendo ou excluindo os arquivos antes de fazer o envio para API, assim fazendo com que ao tentar fazer o envio dos arquivos ocasione um problema ... 
E fiz as verificações a requisição não chega a ser completada então somente um undefined da requisição ...

Gostaria de saber se é possível de alguma forma consistir se os arquivos existem na pasta. Pois assim antes de realizar o envio eu verificaria se os arquivos existem na pasta e caso não exista poderia informar ao usuário que os arquivos foram movidos ou excluídos da pasta corrente.

Answer (score 1):

Conseguir resolver meu problema da seguinte forma. 
Quando os arquivos são movidos ou excluídos da pasta onde os mesmo foram selecionados, no event.target.files do input de seleção e bind do model com o angularJS, o size dos arquivos selecionados fica zerado, conforme pode se observar na imagem abaixo: 
[image: Arquivos após serem movidos ou deletados da pasta, ficando com seu tamanho zerado]

Sendo assim criei um método simples que sempre irá consistir o tamanho dos arquivos antes do envio dos mesmo:

```
function _consistirArquivos(arquivos) {
        var verificadorArquivosIncosistentes = false;
        for (let i = 0; i < arquivos.length; i++) {
            var arquivo = arquivos[i];
            if (arquivo.size == 0) {
               verificadorArquivosIncosistentes  = true;
               break;                        
            }
        }
        return verificadorArquivosIncosistentes                            
};
```